# Django - Suffix all urls with language code

Tags: django, django-urls, django-middleware

I'm working on a multilingual site so I want to suffix all my urls with the current 2-character language code. If no language is specified I want to default to english.

For example:

`mysite.com/` --> `mysite.com/en`

`mysite.com/location` --> `mysite.com/locations/en`

`mysite.com/ar`   will display the arabic site

Since I don't want to add `(?P<language>[a-x]{2})$` to all my urls I'm guessing I should write some middleware to check for the suffix and strip it out?

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the standard way and prefix them with the language code? Django provides a quick way for doing so: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc Thanks i didnt know this existed! Please add it as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment by @Bogdan above I resorted to using the built-in prefixing feature in django.

- I added the `LocaleMiddleware` in my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting
- I added a LANGUAGES setting to specify the languages in my site, in my case it was only English and Arabic so my languages looked like

  `LANGUAGES = (
      ('ar', _('Arabic')),
      ('en', _('English')),
  )`
- In my views I used `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` to access the language code and display the appropriate language in my template